# Do I blast or honk the horn of a car?

Tags: word-choice

One is driving on a freeway.  A truck is about to crash into ones car, so one sounds the car horn.

One could say blast the horn, honk the horn, sound the horn, etc.

Which is the most proper word choice?

Comment: You **blast** the horn in this situation. You **honk** the horn to warn of your presence. You **bip** or **pip** the horn as a gentle reminder.

Comment: @Weather Vane Interesting--I think bip and pip are British.  AmE speakers would probably use "beep" the same way.

Comment: You can also "lean on" the horn, indicating it's a continuous blast.

Comment: You can 'hoot' or even 'toot' your horn as well. (Might be a Brit thing to say.)